# Implementation of WebDAV client on android

Tags: android, webdav

I am using jakarta/slide project for implementing webDAV client on my android device.
I got the all necessary jar files into external library,
my code:

```
package com.android.webdav;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.util.HttpURL;
import org.apache.webdav.lib.WebdavResource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Webdav extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            HttpURL hrl = new HttpURL("serverUrl");
            hrl.setUserInfo("username", "password");
            WebdavResource wdr = new WebdavResource(hrl);
            File fn = new File("remote-file");
            wdr.getMethod(fn);
            File LocFile = new File("mnt/sdcard/test/");
            wdr.putMethod(LocFile);
            wdr.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HttpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

but I am getting error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.webdav.lib.WebdavResource
```

above class already added in jar.
Required help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sardine + http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ does **not** work, because httpclientandroidlib has renamed all package names. See [android sardine + httpclientandroidlib -> new package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187424/android-sardine-httpclientandroidlib-new-package-names)

Answer (score 0):

Sardine + http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/

http://sardine.googlecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/yeonsh/Sardine-Android.