# android sardine + httpclientandroidlib -> new package names

Tags: android, http, webdav, sardine

I followed the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853412/497102 and I ended up, that sardine is not finding any http classes. Well as http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ says correctly alls package names are renamed from

`org.apache.http`

to

`ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib`

and therefore Sardine can not find any classes.

The stackoverflow thread above is blocked and I need a answer to this, how I can use Sardine in Android

App Level: 8, Android 2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Sardine-Android is not based on a new Sardine version and has some problems. For example, cannot get file's size and cannot work with filenames that have white spaces. Still didn't find a solution for this problem, maybe using a different webdav software?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://github.com/yeonsh/Sardine-Android ?